# Mail functionality iphone App Crashes

Tags: iphone, email, crash

While Using email functionality in my App,the App is getting crash if we did'nt sign in at any email address.

Is there anyway to add the exception for this that users gets the Alertview  without having App Crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is you can check whether device can send mail or not like below..

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == NO) {
       //your alertview telling error 
    return;
}
   else
 {
    //your code for sending mail
  }
```

Happy Coding!@!!!